# applicationWillTerminate not being called after app is woken app in background after UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey

Tags: ios, ibeacon, appdelegate, region-monitoring

**Objective:** I am trying to detect when the app shuts down. The applicationWillTerminate is not being called after iOS kills my app.

---

Question:

**applicationWillTerminate** is not being called after app is woken app and then subsequently terminated by iOS (it has normally 10 seconds of time) in background by a location event (e.g. entering beacon region aka **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey**). Why is that?

- Test method 1: http://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/
- Test method 2: added UILocalNotifications

Sequence of events:

- app is not running
- beacon is turned on
- app is woken up by iOS
- after a while (10 seconds usually) app stops running
- however applicationWillTermiante method is not being called.

Comment: applicationWillTerminate is called when your app will be closed not when it will be opened.

Comment: You may want to read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:  as it clearly indicates "This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and purged from memory entirely."  If your app stays in background watching a location, its probably not being purged.

Comment: I have just added a better explanation, I expressed myself badly.

Comment: Are there any other events that are fired which you could use? say `applicationDidEnterBackground:` ?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the app is already started in background mode so that will probably not fire either.  What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly? Usually an app that gets woken up for a location performs a task and shut down, unless you use  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{ [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];  }];` or something similar iOS will kill your app within that timeframe.

Comment: I am logging for all of those and they do occur, the one that does not occur is applicationWillTerminate

Comment: I am trying to detect when the app shuts down. The applicationWillTerminate is not being called after iOS kills my app.